# Android: Call to context menu from NavigationMenu item selected

Tags: java, android, contextmenu

sorry for my English.

I have a problem trying to call ContextMenu in Android.

Android Studio set a listener in a float widget and it Works:

```
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    registerForContextMenu(fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            openContextMenu(fab);
        }
    });
```

But trying to call it when the user press in a item of a NavigationMenu, I'm not sure the correct way to declare:

```
NavigationMenuItemView navigationItemView = (NavigationMenuItemView) findViewById(R.id.nav_call);
```

Then use:

```
openContextMenu(navigationItemView);
```

I have this:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    NavigationMenuItemView navigationItemView = (NavigationMenuItemView) findViewById(R.id.nav_call); //Declare view maybe like this?

    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
        //home
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_call) {
        //Here is my problem
        openContextMenu(navigationItemView);

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

activity_main_drawer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_24dp"
        android:title="Home" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_call"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_call_24dp"
        android:title="Call" />
</group>
```

Of course, it doesn't work because when I press button app will be a crash and give me Null pointer exception:

Log:

> 04-18 00:40:45.561 27548-27548/com.android.test01 E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0xb8a05080 (glSizeof,80)
>   04-18 00:40:45.593 27548-27548/com.android.test01 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>   04-18 00:40:45.593 27548-27548/com.android.test01 W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4d14b20)
>   04-18 00:40:45.593 27548-27548/com.android.test01 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                             Process: com.android.test01, PID: 27548
>                                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.openContextMenu(Activity.java:2933)
>                                                                                 at com.android.test01.MainActivity.onNavigationItemSelected(MainActivity.java:109)
>                                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(NavigationView.java:151)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:811)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:958)
>                                                                                 at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$1.onClick(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:318)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

How is the correct way for the call to a ContextMenu using a Navigation Item?

Thanks for reading! Regards.

Comment: When you have an exception **ALWAYS** post the stacktrace of that exception from logcat and indicate the line where that exception is thrown in your code. Also, showing a context menu for a navigation view item click doesn't really make any sense at all.

Comment: Log added, the line 109 is `openContextMenu(navigationItemView);`
I need to open a context menu because the action call a phone, but there is 3 different phone numbers, so the user need to select one of them. But now you say, maybe I'll add a submenu. Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think this is not possible, and as another user says, it not makes sense.

Then I used a submenu.

I just edited the menu XML file:

activity_main_drawer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_24dp"
        android:title="Home" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_call"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_call_24dp"
        android:title="Call">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_call1"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_call_24dp"
                android:title="Call to A" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_call2"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_call_24dp"
                android:title="Call to B" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_call3"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_call_24dp"
                android:title="Call to C" />
        </menu>
        </item>
</group>
```

And make the validation in the Activity.java file:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
        //Home activity
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_call1) {
        //foo CallNumber(1);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_call2) {
        //foo CallNumber(2);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_call3) {
        //foo CallNumber(3);
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Thanks for reading, regards!